# Most efficient scrolling text

Tags: javascript, html, performance, css

I need to create very CPU efficient scrolling text as smoothly as possible. The reason the performance is so key is that I'm also recording from the user's microphone at the same time. I've tried two things so far:

```
scroller = setInterval(scroll_words, 100);

function scroll_words ()
{
   var words= document.getElementById("words");
   var speed = document.getElementById("word_speed").value;
   var total_height = word.children.length * 18;
   words.scrollTop += 0.1 * 18 * speed;
}
```

This one is noticeably choppy, and it causes significant errors in recording (skipping, or blank spots). Here's my second attempt:

```
var words = document.getElementById("words");
var speed = document.getElementById("word_speed").value;
words.style.webkitTransition = ((18 * words.children.length)/speed)+"s all linear";
words.style.webkitTransform = "translate(0px, -"+(18 * words.children.length)+"px)";
```

This is less harsh on performance (and a lot smoother, since it can do subpixel movement), but it still causes noticeable errors in recording on some computers, especially ones with onboard video.

Is there a way to do this without putting much load on the CPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two quick solutions you can try:

1. Use 3D transformations to force modern browsers to use GPU acceleration
2. Split your text in chunks and only animate the visible chunks, instead of the whole thing. Your chunks should be something like this: [p1p2] [p2p3] [p3p4] etc, 2 pages each.

Comment: 3D transformations did it, it would seem. If I have issues later on, I'll try the second suggestion, but the first seems to have been enough.